# Why are $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\\\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ not similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Why are the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}$ not similar?

I can do a row operation. But on the other hand they don't have the same 
characteristic polynomial. How does it relates to: $A$ is similar to $B$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same canonical form ?

Comment: Equivalent in what sense? They are certainly row equivalent (which forms an equivalence relation).

Comment: What do you mean with equivalent? If you mean similarity, then the characteristic polynomial argument suffices.

Comment: They are clearly not the same.  As to whether they are equivalent depends on what *equivalent* mean here

Comment: I meant similar, I changes it. thanks!!!

Comment: Obviously the matrices have different eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to operate under the assumption that matrices which differ by elementary row operations should have the same characteristic polynomial.

This assumption is false (your matrices provide a counterexample). Elementary row operations preserve the row space and the kernel of a matrix, but not the eigenvectors.

Comment: thats exactly what I was missing,  thanks!!!

Comment: so it is not true to say:
A is similar to B if and only if A and B have the same canonical form ?

Comment: @KIMKES1232 Reading your first comment under this answer makes me wonder why you did not upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

The first matrix, $A$, satisfies $A^{2}=0$.
For the second one, $B$, we see that its square does not equal $0$. This implies that we cannot have $A=S^{-1}BS$ for any $S$ because we would then have $A^{2}=S^{-1}B^{2}S$.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is matrix similarity, not matrix equivalence.

Matrix equivalence merely says:

Are two matrices equivalent, you can transform them into each other, multiplying them with nothing but regular matrices. This is true exactly iff they have same rank.

Comment: so why it is not true to say: A is similar to B if and only if A and B have the same canonical form ?

Comment: You can deduce similarity by using a canonical form, just not one that is as simple as yours. Two matrices are similar iff they have the same Frobenius normal form.

Comment: what is a  Frobenius normal form?

Comment: That's a rather involved question (for which I frankly lack some knowledge). An easier canonical form that is equal to similarity is this: Two matrices are similar, if their Jordan Normal Form is, up to a permutation of blocks, identical. (The Jordan Normal Form then again is a generalization of Diagonalization)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose they were equivalent then there had to exists a invertible matrix $S := \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ such that
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
S^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
holds.
We have
$
S^{-1}
= \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}.
$
Therefore, $(1)$ becomes
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\iff & \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{pmatrix} c d & d^2 \\ -c^2 & -c d \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This yields $cd = 0$ and $-cd = 1$, which clearly is a contradiction.